# declaring an Object in another class

Tags: java, oop

so I have the class `Person`, I then have another class called `Building` and I'm trying to create an object in building giving the person a default location and adding this into my `toString` method, so it displays when I run the program:

```
public class Person {

    private Point p;

    Person(Point np) {
        this.p = np;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Person at " + p.getX() + ", " + p.getY();
    }
```

In the `Building` class I have declared `private Person p` then in `setBuilding` created the object with a new location then added `p` into my `toString` method, I think I got the right idea but whenever I run building it displays "null" and not "Person at " with the set X and Y coordinate which is in my person class. So ive definitely gone wrong somewhere any pointers in the right direction would be a great help thank you.

```
public class Building {
private int xSize = 10;             
private int ySize = 10; // and y
private ArrayList<Room> allRooms;
private Person P;

Building (String first){
allRooms = new ArrayList<Room>(); 
setBuilding(first); 
}

 public void setBuilding(String bS) {
 String[] Space;    

    allRooms.clear(); 
    Space = bS.split(";");  
    //defining the x and y coordinate
    String[] buildingSize = Space[0].split(" "); 
    xSize = Integer.parseInt(buildingSize[0]); 
    ySize =Integer.parseInt(buildingSize[1]); 
    allRooms.add(new Room(Space[1]));
    allRooms.add(new Room(Space[2])); 
    allRooms.add(new Room(Space[3])); 
    Person P = new Person (new Point(2,3));
 }


public String toString() {
     String s = "Building size " + xSize +","+ySize + P + '\n'; 
    for (Room r : allRooms) { //for loop 
        s += r.toString();
    }

    return s;  
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Building b = new Building("11 11;0 0 5 5 3 5;6 0 10 10 6 6;0 5 5 10 2 5");  // create 
    System.out.println(b.toString());               // and print

}
```

}

Comment: Look up "variable shadowing" because that is what you are doing. Change `Person P = new Person (new Point(2,3));` to `P = new Person (new Point(2,3));`

Comment: Hello @curtis B can you add the Point class declaration

Comment: You've never initialized the instance field P. You've initialized a **local** variable also named P: `Person P = new Person (new Point(2,3));`. Replace that with `this.P = ...`. And please, choose better names vor your variables, that respect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response and the easy fix to my problem, @JBNizet sorry im new to java what do you mean by choosing better names for my variables?

Comment: Please check out [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: Also you should avoid using trivial variable names such as `b` or `s` unless they are being used for trivial purposes such as the index of a for loop. Instead use names that have some meaning so that your code becomes self-commenting.

Comment: We mean, be more descriptive. It's not clear if `P` is a person or a point

Comment: Okay thank you, i will take a look at the java naming conventions and change the variable names. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the java naming conventions.

```
private Person person;
```

is the correct naming convention.

Now in your setBuilding method,

```
public void setBuilding(String bS) {
 .
 .
this.person = new Person (new Point(2,3));
```

}

this will do.

Hope this helps. Cheers !!!

Comment: Thank you appreciate your help